# How to create a timechart with percentages by fields using a Splunk query?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a basic Splunk query as shown below. I'm able to create a timechart for the count of similar_events and non-similar_events fields. But, now I'm trying to create a timechart for similar_events and non_similar_events field's percentage instead of count.

How to create a percentage timechart for the similar_events and non_similar_events fields? How can I write the Splunk query?

My basic query:

```
 index='xyz' sourcetype='abc' status='completed' 
    | timechart span=1hr count(eval(_raw like "similar")) as similar_events 
      count(eval(_raw like "non_similar")) as non_similar_events
    | eval total_events = 'similar_events' + 'non_similar_events'
    | eval similar_events_perc = ((similar_events/total_events)*100)."%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add the count variable to get the Total then it is easy to calculate .

Find the query here -

`index=windows source=service State="Running" | timechart span=1m count(eval(match(DisplayName,"Splunk"))) as similar_events  count(eval(match(DisplayName,"SQL"))) as non_similar_events count as Total | eval similiar_events=((similar_events/Total)*100)."%"`

Rest you can do whatever operations you like .

Hope this helps.